# When to use embedded documents MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

After reading the guide for using embedded documents in MongoDB I am still a bit confused as to what they are used for when modelling one-to-one relationships. For example if I had a user which had a `username` an `email` and an `address` which contained `street`, `city`, `state` and `zip`. Why would I model it like:

```
{
  username: "joe",
  email: "joe@example.com",
  address: {
    street: "123 example rd",
    city: "Faketon",
    state: "MA",
    zip: 1234
  }
}
```

when I could do something like this which would often save quite a bit of code when saving and loading from the database:

```
{
  username: "joe",
  email: "joe@example.com",
  street: "123 example rd",
  city: "Faketon",
  state: "MA",
  zip: 1234
}
```

Are there and what are the benefits to using embedded documents for one-to-one relationships? Does it give you any more flexibility or speed with queries? Are there any negative aspects of using embedded documents like this?

Comment: In your example I don't think it would be necessary, but if you had two addresses e.g. billing and shipping, then it would be easier to use embedded docs.

Comment: For future reference, could you provide the link to _"the guide for using embedded documents in MongoDB"_ you read ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Heck, I need that guide :)

Comment: I'd guess this is the guide he's referring to: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several helpful side effects when using embedded documents vs flattening the structure for 1:1 relationships:

- You can specify embedded document in query projections, which saves writing code to get sets of related fields and can help reduce network overhead if your application often works with subsets of the full document.

Using your first example document:

```
{
  username: "joe",
  email: "joe@example.com",
  address: {
    street: "123 example rd",
    city: "Faketon",
    state: "MA",
    zip: 1234
  }
}
```

You can easily get all of the `address` fields by projecting the subdocument:

```
> db.user.find({}, {address:1})
{
  "_id": ObjectId("554a0656f5549fd193161e2e"),
  "address": {
    "street": "123 example rd",
    "city": "Faketon",
    "state": "MA",
    "zip": 1234
  }
}
```

- Embedded documents can provide additional semantic context.

Looking at your second example it may not be clear to another developer whether `state` is meant to be used as part of an address or if it might represent an application state (i.e. one arbitrary interpretation might be "MA" => "Management Approval"). The semantics can get harder to infer as are more fields are added to schema over time, or in cases where some of the fields may not be present in all documents.

Similarly, if you wanted to add `home` and `office` addresses both could have identical fields:

```
{
  "home": {
    "street": "123 example rd",
    "city": "Faketon",
    "state": "MA",
    "zip": 1234
  },
  "work": {
    "street": "456 Longcommuta Way",
    "city": "Busyville",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": 90210
  }
}
```

You could take advantage of the similarity in subdocuments to have reusable code that works with either home or work addresses.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any performance difference.
Both solutions are valid, but you should consider how you'll handle data with your programming language.

Example: with PHP or Java classes, you may want to create two classes, User and Address. Address will be embed in your User class/document. You may also want to reuse the Address class/document elsewhere.

You can see Mongo documents as PHP/Java classes.